# How to convert a state to an index with Julia code

Tags: matrix, indexing, julia, state

I'm going to make a matrix with Julia code, but I'm going to convert the state in rows and columns to index first, so please tell me how. For example, I'm trying to convert the state of a row called (0100000) to an index called 1, what code should I use?

Comment: This question is confusing and difficult to answer. It is not clear what you mean by 'state of a row', or what `0100000` means. Are those the values in the row? Please expand your question, and provide clear examples directly in the question (not just in comments).

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to operate columnwise rather than rowwise in Julia, as it is a column-major language. So let's say you're looking to encode the state of a column containing `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. The best thing would be to make the original matrix a boolean matrix, and use `findall` on the column:

```
julia> M = BitArray([1 0 1 0
                     0 1 0 1
                     1 0 0 1
                     0 0 1 0
                     1 0 0 1
                     1 0 1 1
                     0 0 0 1])
7×4 BitMatrix:
 1  0  1  0
 0  1  0  1
 1  0  0  1
 0  0  1  0
 1  0  0  1
 1  0  1  1
 0  0  0  1

julia> col = @view M[:, 2]
7-element view(::BitMatrix, :, 2) with eltype Bool:
 0
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0

julia> only(findall(col))
2
```

Note that Julia uses 1-based indexes for arrays, so it would be more convenient to decode the state you've given to `2` rather than `1` - because the `1` is in the `2`nd position in the column. If you do need it to be `1` for some other reason, you can of course do `only(findall(col)) - 1`

Comment: I'm trying to convert both rows and columns to indexes. In addition to (0100000), there are many other states (0230000), (6300000), and so on, and we want to specify each matrix value by placing various states in rows and columns. For example
The row is (6010010) and the column is (5000000), and I want to put 0.004 in this position. At this point, if you specify the index for the (6010010) and (5000000) status values and the index is 1 row and 1 column, you want to express (1,1) = 0.004.
I'm curious how to index the status of rows and columns here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that at all. My answer was assuming that you had something like a simple one-hot encoding, and wanted to decode that. It doesn't seem like that's the case, so please add more details to the question, including Julia code and output, about what data you have right now, in what kinds of variables.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, maybe you're looking for https://github.com/mcabbott/AxisKeys.jl , a way to give names ("state values") to the rows and columns and index using them?